# Is there a way of running jest tests sequentially in a Create React App application?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, create-react-app, react-testing-library

I'm using the React Testing Library in an application created using Create React App. am finding that while some of my tests run fine by themselves, if I try and test all at the same time, then they start failing. I wanted to see if running the tests sequentially will get over this issue.

I can see you can run tests inline in jest, but didn't want to eject just to be able to send this parameter thru. I suspect that running all in parallel, is causing some of them to slow down and hence fail and running in series may get over the issue. Appreciate if can share the config to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Basically you can add more `jest` options to the `react-script test` command as following (obviously the option you need here is `--runInBand` to make the test run sequentially):

`package.json`

```json
{
  "scripts": {
    "test:runInBand": "react-scripts test --runInBand"
  }
}
```

Then you run: `npm run test:runInBand`.

Or you can execute your current test with `yarn` (yarn would help you to pass the option down to test command), with this way you don't have to create any new script command:

```sh
yarn test --runInBand

// npm also offers the same thing by adding `--` to separate the options
// just been aware of that lately via the comment below

npm test -- --runInBand
```

Comment: It's not specific to yarn, `npm test -- --runInBand` does the same thing.

Comment: Ah you're right. It's good to know adding `--` to be able to pass the argument down :)

Comment: do you need the `--` with npm?

Comment: Yep `npm` does't pass anything down without adding `--`